# How to migrate Servlet class to Spring MVC controller class?

Tags: spring-mvc

In my project, we have to migrate from Spring Framework 3 to Spring Framework 4. In this project servlet classes had created now i have to migrate into Spring Framework 4 without using servlet classes and have to migrate into corresponding Controller class. So how to migrate init method of servlet in Spring Framework controller. Here is my code

```
public class ABCServlet extends HttpServlet {

static WebApplicationContext ctx;

 public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        if (ctx == null) {
            ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
            ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet

```
public class ABCServlet extends HttpServlet {

static WebApplicationContext ctx;

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        if (ctx == null) {
            ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
            ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see any business logic.

Therefore, you can port from Servlet to Spring Framework 3, or upgrade from Spring Framework 3 to Spring Framework 4 without any concern.